# Porting C++ Builder to Qt

Tags: qt, c++builder

I want to port a C++Builder project to use Qt in its UI.  Does anyone know what the Qt equivalents of the VCL's `TStatusBar`, `TStringGrid`, `TListBox` and `TSpeedButton` components are?

Comment: Oh come on, you didn't even try.

Answer (score 1):

- for `TStatusBar`, use [QStatusBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html)
- for `TListBox`, use [QListBox](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/qlistbox.html) ([Q3ListBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/q3listbox.html) in Qt4) or [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html)
- `TStringGrid` and `TSpeedButton` apparently have no equivalent. Use Qt demo software to see what Qt toolkit proposes and find what you are looking for.

For other classes (not mentioned by OP):

- for `TCheckBox`, use `QCheckBox`
- for `TRadioButton`, use `QRadioButton`
- for `TComboBox`, use `QComboBox`

Comment: What's wrong with the answer, why downvoting?

Comment: replace "T" with "Q" -- except in all of the cases but one

Comment: For `TStringGrid`, you can probably use [`QGridLayout`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html) with [`QLabel`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html) and/or [`QLineEdit`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html) widgets in its cells.

Comment: @M.M: For all class mentioned but one. But it works in general (`TCheckBox`, `TComboBox`, `TRadioButton`...)

Comment: Well there is no QStatusBar object in Qt, so all I did is to put a QFrame in the Gui then transform it to a QStatusbar in the constructor and for TRadioGroup, I used a QListWidget. Thank you for your help @jpo38. According to my research there is no difference between a Button and a SpeedButton, so i used QButton.

Comment: There is a QStatusBar? What about that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatusbar.html. There's also a QButtonGroup: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbuttongroup.html